# Primary job terminated in HPL benchmarking with openmpi

Tags: benchmarking

I am benchmarking my cluster. I do have one processor AMD FX(tm)-8350 type processor and have Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X3210 type. I have compile my hpl with Make.Linux_PII_CBLAS_gm ; with openmpi, cblas and openblas library. It compile good. Running with mpirun in AMD processor it also serves well. But when come to the intel processor it Shows :

Primary job terminated normally, but 1 process returned a non zero exit code. Per user-derection , the job has been aborted.

mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with pid 0 on node node1 exited on signal 4 (Illegal instruction.)

Do I have to compile hpl specifically for intel processor? Any suggestion regarding this problem will be a lot helpful.

Comment: if you compiled `hpl` or its dependency (such as `openblas`) specifically for AMD, then it might not run on Intel processor.

Comment: I actuallly added openblas, So does that means openblas could be an Issue,

Comment: That is definitely a suspect. Try to generate a core and then check the stack trace to figure out in which subroutine the crash occurs.